# Displaying comments to the right post

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, backend

So I'm trying to get comments to go to the post they are put on. However, when I make a comment, a new collection gets made rather than it going to the post's ID.

How it looks: (the grey code at the bottom of this collection is the comment ID that was made after I added a comment. This is the problem.)
[image]

How I want it to look:
[image]

The firestore code I am using:

```
class FirestoreMethods {
  Future<void> postComment(String postId, String text, String uid, String name,
      String profilePic) async {
    try {
      if (text.isNotEmpty) {
        String commentId = const Uuid().v1();
        await postsRef
            .doc(uid)
            .collection('userPosts')
            .doc(postId)
            .collection('comments')
            .doc(commentId)
            .set({
          'profilePic': profilePic,
          'name': name,
          'uid': uid,
          'text': text,
          'commentId': commentId,
          'datePublished': DateTime.now()
        });
      } else {}
    } catch (e) {
      print(
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The collection that is made in Image 1 needs to go in to a subcollection of the `userPosts` as shown in image 2. How can I do this?

Comment: Your document structure is too much complicated and not logical. In a post collection, hold posts not posts with user ID created it. If he wants to make another post, how do you get a new `ID` as his `uid`?

Comment: So why you call user collection a `posts`? If it were `users/uid/posts/postId` it would be easy to understand.

Comment: And easiest would be `posts/postID` and `comments/commetID` post data: `{ owner: uid, author: ... }` comment data: `{owner: uid, belongsToPost: postID, author: ...}`

Comment: No time to talk, watch/read some tutorials.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue in your postsref so you can try something like this:

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc(uid).collection('userPosts').doc(postId).collection('comments').doc(commentId).set({
          'profilePic': profilePic,
          'name': name,
          'uid': uid,
          'text': text,
          'commentId': commentId,
          'datePublished': DateTime.now()
        });
```

Just make sure that you are passing proper **uid**, **postId**, and **commentId**

Comment: @harrie It's because you have too much complicated structure. New user sending his `uid` as post `id` ?